# Logging in user in Windows 2008 server using LogonUser fails on LogonType LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE

Tags: windows-server-2008, uac, cluster, windows-authentication

I am using [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to logon an account to Windows 2008 R2 server on a domain with clusterring.

When using LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE as LogonType, I successfully login.

When using LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE as LogonType, Login fails, EventViewer says:

An account failed to log on.
Logon Type:         5

Account For Which Logon Failed:

```
Security ID:        NULL SID
Account Name:       thename
Account Domain:     thedomain
Logon ID: 0x1009371c Logon Type: 5

Failure Information:
Failure Reason:     The user has not been granted the requested logon type at this machine.
Status:         0xc000015b
Sub Status:     0x0
```

Was not sure if its for superuser or stackoverflow (calling LogonUser from C# code), but I guess its some Windows server issue*.

EventID = 4625

Edit:
Found that - 
0xc000015b  The user has not been granted the requested logon type (aka logon right) at this machine

Edit: Should be serverfault question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after deep research found that in the Local Security Policy, under User Right Assignment

"Log on as a service" should be granted to users logging in with LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE logon type.